# How do I retrieve data from within a handlebars loop and use it within backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a problem that has left me scratching my head for days. My knowledge of JavaScript is not great, I'm still learning, and to top it off I'm working on a project where I'm forced to use handlebars, Marionette and other stuff I'm not familiar with.

I have a handlebars template which looks like this:

```
{{#if images}}
    {{#each images}}
        <div class="image-thumbnail">
            <i class="delete-button" style="cursor:pointer" id="delete-button-id" data-imgid="{{id}}"></i>
            <img src="{{thumbnail}}"/></a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

This all looks fine when the page loads, no problems there. If I put `{{id}}` between `<i>{{id}}</i>` then the value is output correctly to the browser. The problem I'm having is accessing that id from a pop-up which I'm generating using:

```
deleteImage: function(event) {
    new DeleteView({model: new Backbone.Model()}).render().$el.appendTo('body');
},
```

I've tried adding the following:

```
new DeleteView({model: new Backbone.Model({ imgid: imageID })}).render().$el.appendTo('body');
```

And setting `imgid` using:

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById('delete-button-id');
var imageID = imageElement.getAttribute('data-imgid');
```

Unfortunately this only gets the last `imgid` and it's the same for every one. The page is basically a list of photos which are generated from the handlebars loop. There can be dozens on the page at once, and the `imgid` I get when the pop-up fires needs to be specific to the one I clicked.

My main view for the page where the images appear:

```
 var ThumbnailView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     template: getTemplate('profile/thumbnail'),
     className: 'main-gallery',
     events: {
         'click .delete-button': 'deleteImage'
     }

     ... more code follows ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I need to get the correct dynamically-generated `imgid` from `data-imgid="{{id}}"` but I'm only getting the same one each time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the last ID each time is because you are selecting the element via the ID attribute:

```
document.getElementById('delete-button-id');
```

and unfortunately, your template has `id="delete-button-id"` on *each* of the `<i>` elements being rendered, thus when you try to do `document.getElementById` it will always return the last element with that attribute. The `id` attribute (unlike `class`) is intended to be unique, and according to W3C it must be unique in the document. If it isn't, it can cause issues like the one you're seeing (see here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id, https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

To fix this, remove the `id` attribute from the `<i>`. Also remove the dangling `</a>` as well. Your template should now look like:

```
{{#each images}}
    <div class="image-thumbnail">
        <i class="delete-button" style="cursor:pointer" data-imgid="{{id}}"></i>
        <img src="{{thumbnail}}"/>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Now when you're trying to select the element in `deleteImage`, you can do so via jQuery/Marionette by doing:

```
var imageId = this.$(event.currentTarget).data('imgid');
```

Or if you're keen on using plain JavaScript, you can obtain the ID like so:

```
var imageId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-imgid');
```

And that should do it. You can play around with this JSBin to see how it will work:
https://jsbin.com/fotiqisoye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you, this advice was perfect and solved my problem! Much appreciated sir!

Comment: @SheriffOfNottingham happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

the marionette way to restructure this solution would be to replace your each loop with a CompositeView, and feed it a collection of models, which will each render an ItemView, which will be represented in your dom as a single line-item of image.

when you click delete on that image, the ItemView receives the event, and the model.id passed into it will be correct.

more on this here: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.compositeview.html

hope this helps